# How to get return from promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios

I want to get data through axios for setting the header, but getAxios1 and 2 seem slower then return header need to do refresh to reload the header.
How can make return header after getAxios1 and 2.

I tried to do below code to step by step get data then output header, but it still not work.

```
export const getHeader = (props: IAppProps) => {
  const promises = [];
  promises.push(getAxios1());
  promises.push(getAxios2());
  Promise.all(promises).then(d => {
  return   (<ErrorBoundary>
          <Header
          isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated}
          isAdmin={props.isAdmin}
          isUser={props.isUser}
          isFoPayroll={props.isStaff}
          ribbonEnv={props.ribbonEnv}
          isInProduction={props.isInProduction}
          isSwaggerEnabled={props.isSwaggerEnabled}
        />);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const getHeader = (props: IAppProps) => {
  const [fetched, setFetchStatus] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const promises = [];
  promises.push(getAxios1());
  promises.push(getAxios2());
  Promise.all(promises).then(d => {
    setFetchStatus(true);
    setData(d);
  });

  // use data 
  return  fetched && (<ErrorBoundary>
          <Header
          isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated}
          isAdmin={props.isAdmin}
          isUser={props.isUser}
          isFoPayroll={props.isFoPayroll}
          ribbonEnv={props.ribbonEnv}
          isInProduction={props.isInProduction}
          isSwaggerEnabled={props.isSwaggerEnabled}
        />);
```

Also add another state to save the fetched data. 
I have edited. Hope this helps